# Blocking vs non-blocking call mediator in API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm wondering if some can explain why the call mediator only works in WSO2 API Manager (2.x) when you set `blocking=true` in the properties of the call mediator.

I have tested the same sequence in API manager and ESB and a sequence with the following snippet works fine in ESB, but not in API manager unless I set `blocking=true` on the call mediator

```
  <call description="Get Auth token">
<endpoint>
  <http method="get" trace="disable" uri-template="https://some.service.com/auth/api/token"/>
</endpoint>
```

When I use this in API manager, I do get a response but the sequence does not continue.

Is there a way to use the non-blocking call mediator in API manager?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: What are the esb and apim versions?

Comment: APIM 2.0 and ESB 4.9 and 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same today, and `blocking=true` is to do synchronous messaging, whereas `blocking=false` which is to do asynchronous messaging.

You need to send a 202 response before the sequence goes on.